# How to restore Override Default button for default value in SSRS parameters configuration

Tags: reporting-services

If I click on an Override Default button, a textbox appears. How do I get the Override Default button back?

[image: SSRS Properties]
<sub>(source: [socha.com](http://www.socha.com/blogs/john/uploaded_images/CustomizingReportParametersforTeamFounda_BF8D/Parameters_thumb.png))</sub>

Comment: lol i went back to googling the answer and this is already the top result. it's only been 5 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-deploy the report to that folder, and the default settings (and therefore the option to override them) will be restored.

Answer (score 0):

Redeploying the reports does not change the parameter settings. I had to delete the report on the report server first and then deploy it again and than I had the button back.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to find out what was set on the default field and re-add.
Example, I messed up one of my default values on a "Date" field.
Steps to fix:

1. Edit a similar report that had the same field/default value. (Click the down arrow on the report on the web interface and select `Edit` in `Report Builder`).
2. On the folder structure on the left expand `Parameters` and double click the parameter you want to fix.
3. Click `Default Value` on the `Report Parameter Properties` pop up window.
4. Click the `fx` button and paste the parameter you grabbed from the working report.  In my case the string was `=datetime.Now()`.

Answer (score 0):

Only way is to delete report and deploy it again. you can make it quickly:

1. open report in report designer and keep it open
2. go to reporting service web and delete opened report
3. go back to report designer and click save buton (or ctrl+s)

Answer (score 0):

More by accident than intention I fought this issue and discovered a method that was simple.  I have only repeated it once but it had the same results.
On the SSRS Report Parameters Properties dialog in Report Builder:

1. Select the parameter that is the problem
2. Select "Default Values" tab
3. Select the "Specify Values" Dialog
4. Set the value to something valid
5. Select OK  and run the report
6. When it is complete, set the parameter value to whatever you would like it to be going forward
7. save the report

Now, if you go into the web interface, select manage from the report's drop down menu.  Then if you look at parameters section of the management tab the "Override Default" button should be restored.

End Note:  The button's appearance seems to be tied to the object property 
    `<DynamicDefaultValue>True</DynamicDefaultValue>`

of the parameter.  This is found in "Parameter" field of the "Catalog" table in the ReportServer database.  To test the dependency I wrote a quick WPF app with an XML viewer that allowed me to browse the parameters independently.  I created a dummy SSRS report and by adding and removing that node in the XML properties could make the button appear and disappear.  If I get around to making the connection string dynamic I will make the app available in this post.